# php preg_match fail to return not matching

Tags: php, preg-match

i have the following php code for validate First Name, Last Name

```
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\p{Greek}\s]+$/u", "Hello & World!", $m)) 
{
    //validation pass
    echo "validation pass";
}
else
{
    //validation failed
    var_dump($m);
    echo "validation failed";
}
```

The problem is that i was expecting on $m[0] to found the non matching elements so echo a message like

```
echo "{$m[0]} is not allow character(s)";
```

but the $m variable is an empty array

Any help appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You can't do that with a single regex, as the non-matching chars are not stored after a match is failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with a single regex, as the non-matching chars are not stored after a match is failed.

You may use a kind of an inverted pattern after failing a match, like

```
$s = "Hello & World!";
if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z\p{Greek}\s]+$/u", $s)) {
    echo "validation pass"; //validation pass
}
else {
    if (preg_match_all('~[^A-Za-z\p{Greek}\s]~u', $s, $m)) { //validation failed
        var_dump($m[0]);
    }
    echo "validation failed";
}
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/I92M5G). Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "&"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "!"
}
validation failed
```

The `[^A-Za-z\p{Greek}\s]` pattern is a [**negated character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any char other than the one(s) defined in the class: ASCII and Greek letters and whitespaces.